# making parallel POST requests using async.js and limiting the number of requests to 3 at a given time

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, asynchronous, request

I need to make concurrent POST requests to fetch data from server, but the number of concurrent requests to be made at a given time should be 5 and once those are complete then the next 5 requests can fire and then it should go on until the upper limit is reached.

In order to do this i'm trying to use async, and since mine is a node app i'm requiring it after npm install in my JS module. I would like to know whether i can use async.parallelLimit (or) async.eachLimit for this requirement. In both of them it looks like we can mention the limit. I was referring a nice example from here http://www.devblogrbmz.com/playing-around-with-async-js/ for using eachLimit.

I make use of "request" module to POST requests to server. Fundamentally the end scenario is that when a startDate and endDate is provided i need to get the number of days b/w them including start and end and then i need to make POST requests for each date to fetch the data from server. While making request for each date, using async limit parameter i need to limit it to 5 so at a given point of time only 5 POST requests would be made and then the next 5 would start after that and it would go on until the upper limit.

Can anyone suggest which one i can use for this async. parallelLimit or eachLimit?

Here is how the code looks using forEachLimit,

```
var diffDays = ['2016-05-31', '2016-06-01', '2016-06-02', '2016-06-03', '2016-06-04', '2016-06-05', '2016-06-06']

async.forEachOfLimit(diffDays, 3, function (value, key, callback) {
    console.log(value + " @forEach");
    makeRequest(value),
    callback();
}, function (error, results) {
    if(error) {
        console.log('An error occured ' + error);
    }
});
```

makeRequest is where i'm performing a POST request operation

```
function makeRequest (days) {
request({
    url     : "/api/retrieveEndPoint",
    method  : "POST",
    headers : options,
    json    : {
                "path": days
              }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
      if(body) {
        console.log(days + " @makeRequest");
      }
      else if (error) {
        console.log('An error occured ' + error);
      }
})};
```

so essentially if i see console.log with @forEach it prints from 31 May through 06 Jun 2016. On the other hand if i see the console.log with @makeRequest it prints the dates in a random order as it performs the request. I would like to maintain the same order and also it should make 3 request at a given point of time.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose depending on which one fits your scenario better and if the requests need to be executed one after the other. Basically I think you should be fine with using `parallelLimit` as all the requests do not depend on each other and it is more about flow control and executing some tasks than iterating over a collection in an async way.

Comment: thank you. I added the code to my original query. but the makeRequest function runs irrespective of the limit i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be able to maintain order and get the benefits of parallel processing without some work. async.forEachOfLimit should send the requests in order but you have no assurance that they will return in order. If you are doing something that depends on collecting the results in order then you can make use of the index:

```
var diffDays = ['2016-05-31', '2016-06-01', '2016-06-02', '2016-06-03', '2016-06-04', '2016-06-05', '2016-06-06'];
var diffResults = new Array(diffDays.length);

async.forEachOfLimit(diffDays, 3, function (value, key, callback) {
    console.log(value + " @forEach");
    makeRequest(value diffResults, key);
    ...
}, function(err){ //<-- there is no second argument in async.forEachOfLimit
  diffResults.forEach... // assuming no error process in order results
});
```

Then make request becomes:

```
function makeRequest (days, resultBuf, resultIndex) {
request({
    url     : "/api/retrieveEndPoint",
    method  : "POST",
    headers : options,
    json    : {
                "path": days
              }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
      if(body) {
        console.log(days + " @makeRequest");
        resultBuf[resultIdx] = body; //in order results collected

      }
      else if (error) {
        console.log('An error occured ' + error);
      }
})};
```